# Titles of \tcolorbox in different toc levels

Tags: table-of-contents, tcolorbox

I have several **tcolorbox**es in my document:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[list inside=toc]{mybox}[1]{title={#1}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{First section}

\begin{mybox}{My title}
content
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}{My title}
content
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}{My title}
content
\end{mybox}

\section{Second section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}

\begin{mybox}{My title}
content
\end{mybox}

\subsection{Second subsection}

\begin{mybox}{My title}
content
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

and I'd like their titles to appear in my `\tableofcontents`. As you can see, these coloboxes are inside `\section`s, a `subsection`s... or any other level.

The problem is despite that, they all have the same indent level (as subsubsection) in the rendered table:

[image]

while I'm expecting to have:

[image]

All I can see is the use of `\addcontentsline`, but I'd rather avoid the need to write the section level (`{section}`, `{subsection}`...) whenever I use a box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[list inside=toc,list type=\noexpand\currentseclevel]{mybox}[1]{title={#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\currentseclevel{%
        \ifnum \c@subsubsection = 0 
             \ifnum \c@subsection = 0
                     section%
              \else
                     subsection%
              \fi 
          \else 
              subsubsection% 
          \fi}
\makeatletter                   
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{First section}

\begin{mybox}{My title}
content
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}{My title}
content
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}{My title}
content
\end{mybox}

\section{Second section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsubsection{First subsubsection}

\begin{mybox}{My title}
content
\end{mybox}

\subsection{Second subsection}

\begin{mybox}{My title}
content
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]